# how to remove all the application from ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04

how to remove all the application from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?
i installed a lot of software's and packages ,i don't remember what all are they......can you please help me  ? i want to the OS like fresh installed 
thank you

Comment: That duplicate was rather old and I'm not sure I'd follow any of them directly.  Ubuntu desktop as installed can be see by looking here https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-desktop; I'd just load `aptitude` (at terminal) and remove anything there I didn't use, then re-install `ubuntu-desktop` which should drag back what you are asking for.  I've seen scripts that do it (you can see what you've added usually in logs, but with snaps/flatpaks/etc & many methods there is no one place to look...)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does not have button for factory reset. Maybe you can try install application and key [Resetter](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter/releases/latest) to do it.

After downloading it, from `~/Downloads` you must:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi add-apt-key_1.0-0.5_all.deb
sudo gdebi resetter_3.0.0-stable_all.deb
```

After it you can do:

```
sudo resetter
```

If you choose automatic reset, your system will have a factory reset.

Comment: Very interesting but users probably may also want to clean up their home folders.

Comment: @DKBose Resetter does that too. I explained that in an answer to the duplicate target question.

Comment: thank you for comment